# Why is my mac1 gpu not working in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, apple-m1, training-data, pytorch-lightning

python train_torch.py --train --max_epochs 2

```
PyTorch version:1.12.1
MPS 장치를 지원하도록 build 되었는지: True
MPS 장치가 사용 가능한지: True

INFO:root:Namespace(chat=False, sentiment='0', model_params='model_chp/model_-last.ckpt', train=True, max_len=32, batch_size=40, lr=5e-05, warmup_ratio=0.1, logger=True, checkpoint_callback=True, default_root_dir=None, gradient_clip_val=0, process_position=0, num_nodes=1, num_processes=1, gpus=None, auto_select_gpus=False, tpu_cores=None, log_gpu_memory=None, progress_bar_refresh_rate=None, overfit_batches=0.0, track_grad_norm=-1, check_val_every_n_epoch=1, fast_dev_run=False, accumulate_grad_batches=1, max_epochs=2, min_epochs=None, max_steps=None, min_steps=None, limit_train_batches=1.0, limit_val_batches=1.0, limit_test_batches=1.0, limit_predict_batches=1.0, val_check_interval=1.0, flush_logs_every_n_steps=100, log_every_n_steps=50, accelerator=None, sync_batchnorm=False, precision=32, weights_summary='top', weights_save_path=None, num_sanity_val_steps=2, truncated_bptt_steps=None, resume_from_checkpoint=None, profiler=None, benchmark=False, deterministic=False, reload_dataloaders_every_epoch=False, auto_lr_find=False, replace_sampler_ddp=True, terminate_on_nan=False, auto_scale_batch_size=False, prepare_data_per_node=True, plugins=None, amp_backend='native', amp_level='O2', distributed_backend=None, automatic_optimization=None, move_metrics_to_cpu=False, enable_pl_optimizer=None, multiple_trainloader_mode='max_size_cycle', stochastic_weight_avg=False)
GPU available: False, used: False
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
```

-> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'get_cosine_schedule_with_warmup..lr_lambda'

To do deep learning,
python train_torch.py --train --max_epochs 2
Syntax used successfully.
However, the following error appears and it says accelerator=None
I don't know what to do. I ask for your help me.

I was able to see the tracing in Google colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the pytorch version you are using does not have mps acceleration, you should download the nightly version of pytorch. Pytorch version 1.13 does how mps acceleration.

[image: Download this version!!]

It will have some issues because it is not the stable version.